# ASP.NET Grid column width changing when no records find with filter condition, javascript used for filter

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Iam facing issue like, when i filter grid using javascript the grid coulmns width is changing and it is not aligned with texboxes placed on top of grid when no records found with filter conditions. When records found with filter conditions aligment is fine with textboxes place above of each column of grid, but not records found with filter conditions automatically grid coulmn width is changing and aligned with text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If the textboxes are outside the Table (Grid), the column widths will mostly be different. The browser sizes the columns automatically based on its contents. You must specify a width for each column like

```
<td style='width:200px'></td>
```

Or the other option would be to place the textboxes inside the Grid in your HeaderTemplate